# Div position fixed with respect to another div

Tags: css, html, css-position

I have the following html code:

```
<div data-role="content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the following css

```
.container{
    width:310px;
    height:224px;
    position:relative;
    background-image:url(../images/background_1.jpg);
   background-size:contain;
}
.child{
    width:125px;
    height:125px;
    postion:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:50px;
    background-image:url(../images/child.png);
    background-size:contain;
}
```

I want the child div to stay at a fixed position with respect to its parent, but the child div does not move.

Comment: what do you mean with "wrt"?

Comment: What is currently wrong with your code?

Comment: so here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bLu3T/ with background-colors. seems all good child div is positioned wrt its parent container @MathijsFlietstra thank you

Comment: sorry, I mean what @caramba says. The code is wrong because the child div is at the top left of its parent instead of top:100px, left:100px

Comment: sorry, it's a very stupid typo: in the child I wrote "postion" instead of "position"

Comment: Please delete this question if you already solve the typo error. Not necessary to give rep points

Comment: @user3098549 many (most?) decent html/css editors will provide syntax highlighting to prevent this sort of typo-error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/bLu3T/1/

you have to write

```
position:absolute;
```

not

```
postion:absolute;
```

Answer (score 0):

You spelled position wrong in the CSS...

```
.child{
    width:125px;
    height:125px;
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:50px;
    background-image:url(../images/child.png);
    background-size:contain;
}
```

I tried it out and it seemed to work for me.

Comment: sorry, just noticed that someone else hit submit before I did...LOL